# Adding images to LibGDX project assets

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I quickly created an image in Microsoft Paint and saved it as ***ace.png***.
I also refreshed the project using F5.  I cleaned the project as well through *Project -> Clean...*

When I tried to run the project, an error occurs:

*Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/ace.png*

[Here is an image showing that I have ace.png saved in the correct place and it also shows that in my Package Explorer, it doesn't show the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clHNR.png)

How do I update the assets/data folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your project snapshot, it seems ace.png is not in the data folder. You have to copy the image to assets/data/ in Android project. (You can just drag and drop the file from Windows Explorer to Eclipse.) 
Also try refreshing the project if you're sure the file is there. (Click on the project in Project Explorer and hit F5.)

Please let me know if this helps.

[image]